# How to Delete a Row or Disable Delete Button for specific row in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am facing a problem in how to disable `GridView` `Delete` `Button` for `rowindex = 0`.

Secondly, I want to `Delete` a `Row` on `Delete` `Button` clicked.

My `GridView` is used here for taking data only. I am using a k to create new row and serve it as `DataSource` for `GridView`.

```
  <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkDone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWorkDone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Time spent">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlHours">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewRow" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" 
                        onclick="btnAddNewRow_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
```

but I could not figure out what to implement inside event `RowDeleting`

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
           //Here i am not getting
        }



private void SetInitialRow()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("WorkDone", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeSpent", typeof(string)));
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
            dr["WorkDone"] = string.Empty;
            dr["TimeSpent"] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            //Store the DataTable in ViewState
            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

            Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
            foreach(GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
            {
                if(row.RowIndex == 0)
                {
                    //Delete button must be disabled
                }
            }
        }

   private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;

            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //extract the TextBox values
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtWorkDone");
                        DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlHours");

                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["WorkDone"] = box1.Text;
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["TimeSpent"] = box2.SelectedItem.Text;


                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                    Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                    Gridview1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("ViewState is null");
            }

            //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
            SetPreviousData();
        }
        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtWorkDone");
                        DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ddlHours");
                        box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["WorkDone"].ToString();
                        box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["TimeSpent"].ToString();
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Help please any one!!

Comment: i can't see any Delete button in your Grid view. Please put complete code.

Comment: @KrunalPatil i am using autogenerateddelete button

Comment: Did you try to do it on the OnRowDataBound event? When the rows are generated you can do something like  e.Row.Cells[x].Enabled = false; x being the column position of the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#region"VCoupons"
    private void SetInitialRow()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
       //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));


        dr = dt.NewRow();
      //  dr["RowNumber"] = 1;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.TableName = "Coupons";
        //Store the DataTable in ViewState

        ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt;

        GridviewCoupon.DataSource = dt;
        GridviewCoupon.DataBind();


    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt_CouponData = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dt_CouponData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                for (int i = 1; i <= dt_CouponData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values


                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");




                    drCurrentRow = dt_CouponData.NewRow();

                    //drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                    rowIndex++;

                }

                //add new row to DataTable
                dt_CouponData.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState

                ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt_CouponData;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                GridviewCoupon.DataSource = dt_CouponData;
                GridviewCoupon.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        int n = dt.Rows.Count;

        if (dt.Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column2"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column3"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column4"].ToString() == "")
        {
            SetPreviousData();
        }
        else
        {
            SetData();
        }
    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox4");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;

                }

            }
        }
    }
    private void SetData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];

            int n = dt.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[j]["Column1"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column1"].ToString() && dt.Rows[j]["Column2"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column2"].ToString() && dt.Rows[j]["Column3"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column3"].ToString() && dt.Rows[j]["Column4"].ToString() == dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column4"].ToString())
                    {
                        dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column1"] = "";
                        dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column2"] = "";
                        dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column3"] = "";
                        dt.Rows[j + 1]["Column4"] = "";

                    }
                }
            }
            if (dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column1"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column2"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column3"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column4"].ToString() == "")
            {
                dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column1"] = dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column1"];
                dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column2"] = dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column2"];
                dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column3"] = dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column3"];
                dt.Rows[n - 2]["Column4"] = dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column4"];

                dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column1"]="";
                dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column2"]="";
                dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column3"]="";
                dt.Rows[n - 1]["Column4"]="";

            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox4");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;

                }

            }
            int b = dt.Rows.Count;


            //Rebind the Grid with the current data

        }
    }
    private void SaveCoupons()
    {

        //int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt_CouponData = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dt_CouponData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dt_CouponData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values


                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");




                    drCurrentRow = dt_CouponData.NewRow();

                   // drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                    // rowIndex++;

                }

                dt_CouponData.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //add new row to DataTable

                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt_CouponData;



            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }



    }
    private void Save()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt_CouponData = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dt_CouponData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {


                for (int i = 0; i < dt_CouponData.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values


                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");




                    drCurrentRow = dt_CouponData.NewRow();

                    //drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column4"] = box4.Text;
                    // rowIndex++;

                }

                //add new row to DataTable
                dt_CouponData.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                int n = dt_CouponData.Rows.Count;
                if (dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column1"].ToString() == "" && dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column2"].ToString() == "" && dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column3"].ToString() == "" && dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column4"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column1"] = dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 1]["Column1"];
                    dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column2"] = dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 1]["Column2"];
                    dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column3"] = dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 1]["Column3"];
                    dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 2]["Column4"] = dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 1]["Column4"];

                    dt_CouponData.Rows[n - 1].Delete();

                }
                int b = dt_CouponData.Rows.Count;


                int a = b - 1;
                if (dt_CouponData.Rows[a]["Column1"].ToString() == dt_CouponData.Rows[a - 1]["Column1"].ToString() && dt_CouponData.Rows[a]["Column2"].ToString() == dt_CouponData.Rows[a - 1]["Column2"].ToString() && dt_CouponData.Rows[a]["Column3"].ToString() == dt_CouponData.Rows[a - 1]["Column3"].ToString() && dt_CouponData.Rows[a]["Column4"].ToString() == dt_CouponData.Rows[a - 1]["Column4"].ToString())
                {
                    dt_CouponData.Rows[a].Delete();
                }
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt_CouponData;



            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }



    }
    private void SetPrevious()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["dt_CouponData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];
            int o = 1;
            int b = dt.Rows.Count;
            int a = b - 1;
            GridviewCoupon.DataSource = dt;
            if (dt.Rows[0]["Column2"].ToString() == "")
            {
                dt.Rows[0].Delete();
            }

            //else if (dt.Rows[a]["Column1"].ToString() == dt.Rows[a - 1]["Column1"].ToString() && dt.Rows[a]["Column2"].ToString() == dt.Rows[a - 1]["Column2"].ToString() && dt.Rows[a]["Column3"].ToString() == dt.Rows[a - 1]["Column3"].ToString() && dt.Rows[a]["Column4"].ToString() == dt.Rows[a - 1]["Column4"].ToString())
            //{
            //    dt.Rows[a].Delete();
            //}
            //if (dt.Rows[o]["Column1"].ToString() == dt.Rows[o - 1]["Column1"].ToString() && dt.Rows[o]["Column2"].ToString() == dt.Rows[o - 1]["Column2"].ToString() && dt.Rows[o]["Column3"].ToString() == dt.Rows[o - 1]["Column3"].ToString() && dt.Rows[o]["Column4"].ToString() == dt.Rows[o - 1]["Column4"].ToString())
            //{
            //    dt.Rows[0].Delete();
            //}
            GridviewCoupon.DataBind();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = dt.Rows.Count;

                ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt;


                for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridviewCoupon.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox4");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

                    //if (rowIndex<dt.Rows.Count-1)
                    //{
                    //    rowIndex++;
                    //}

                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridviewCoupon_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.CommandName == "More")
        {
            objENT = new ENT();
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt_CouponData"];

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            if (dt.Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column2"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column3"].ToString() == "" && dt.Rows[0]["Column4"].ToString() == "")
            {
                index++;

            }
            Save();
            int count = dt.Rows.Count;
            if (count == index)
            {
                dt.Rows[index - 1].Delete();
            }
            else
            {
                dt.Rows[index].Delete();
            }
            ViewState["dt_CouponData"] = dt;

            SetPrevious();


        }
    }


    protected void GridviewCoupon_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button Delete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
            DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
            int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                Delete.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Delete.Visible = true;
            }

        }

    }
    #endregion
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%">
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                        <div class="container-fluid col-sm-10">

                            <asp:GridView ID="GridviewCoupon" OnRowEditing="GridviewCoupon_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GridviewCoupon_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridviewCoupon_RowCommand" runat="server" Enabled="false" Style="text-align: center" ShowFooter="true" Width="99%"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Sr No" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC" />--%>
                                    <%--   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="txtbox0" Text='<%# Bind("RowNumber")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                    <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Survey Number" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxS" CssClass="form-control" required="required" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Coupon Code" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" required="required" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Coupon Description" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" MaxLength="250" required="required" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"  required="required" placeholder="DD/MMM/YYYY" CssClass="form-control cal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"  required="required" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99CCCC">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete"  Text="Delete"
                                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                                CommandName="More" CssClass="btn-primary btn"
                                                Style="padding-top: 1%; padding-bottom: 1%; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>


                                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" CssClass="btn-toolbar btn" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                                <%--    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />--%>
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
                            </asp:GridView>

                    </div>
```

here is the whole code came through but took me like 1-2 days:)
hope it helps

Comment: just change the columns in grid and code as u need it Hope it helps:)